# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'createCredentialsXML'

Tags: python, python-3.x, modulenotfounderror

I have a question about my new python project. It is the first time that I use different folders for my project.

I have the following structure:

```
project
  src
    securityFunc
      __init__.py
      createCredentialsXML.py
    main.py
```

I work in PyCharm environment.
After pressing Play i get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\project\src\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from securityFunc import *
  File "C:\project\src\securityFunc\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from createCredentialsXML import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'createCredentialsXML'
```

My main function looks like this:

```
from securityFunc import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate_key()
```

`__init__.py:`

```
from createCredentialsXML import *
```

createCredentialsXML.py:

```
def generate_key():
    key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(os.urandom(2048))

    with open("../key/secret.key", "wb") as key_file:
        key_file.write(key)
```

I tried using Path or sys.path to fix the problem. But it does not work.

Can you please tell me how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're doing a relative import, you need to add a . before your module name:

```
from .createCredentialsXML import *
```

The dot means the module is found in the same directory as the code importing the code.

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 0):

`createCredentialsXML.py` works in the module `securityFunc`; you must specify the scope of the import. Using

```py
from securityFunc.createCredentialsXML import *
```

in `securityFunc.__init__.py` should work.